# Few problems, when running a test method using multiple threads with TestNG

Tags: java, multithreading, testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am facing a problem, when running a test method using multiple threads with TestNG.

The test method is ran two times using two threads with below configuration:

```
@Test(threadPoolSize=2,invocationCount=2)
public void mainRun() { ... }
```

It is launching two browsers for executing the test method in parallel as expected. After launching the browsers, it has to type some text in a text box. So, during this step, the text was sent to text box 'twice' in one browser and the other browser was idle.

Can someone please guide me how to overcome this problem?

Comment: Can someone pls help me in this?

Comment: I need to see the rest of your code. You may have an issue with your driver instantiation.

Comment: @Robbie: The rest of the code is calling a driver setup method.. driver=new FirefoxDriver(dc);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your driver is being stored in a static property, therefore both threads are accessing it simultaneously, which would account for the behaviour you are seeing.

Making the driver a class instance property would only resolve the issue if TestNG creates a new class instance for each invocation rather than share the same class instance.  I do not know how TestNG works in this way, so cannot say whether it will fix your problem.

If you want to have the same webdriver test, run many times in parallel threads using @invocationCount, then your test method must be isolated and atomic, and using a static webdriver does not support this.

To allow static methods to access the webdriver instances, then you will have to pass the webdriver object into the static method as an argument;

e.g.

```
public static void doSomethingFoo(WebDriver driver) {

    // do something to the driver
}
```

There are other ways run parallel threads of different tests methods in TestNG such as creating a suite xml file, but even this will have the same problem caused by the use of a static property to store the webdriver instance.

Perhaps the use of this static property is not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks Robbie, making the driver object as non-static and passing as an argument for static methods is resolved my problem. Thanks for clarifying as well.!!

Answer (score 1):

I am wondering if your driver object is a class property and is therefore shared between invocations? Potentially the two threads are referencing the same property. Although I am not sure how TestNG works when running a method multiple times, this is a problem when running different methods in the same class in parallel.

trying defining the propery at method level and let me know what happens.

Comment: Just seen your comment with code. I think the above is your problem. Move the setup code within the method AND declare 'driver' within the method.

Comment: If you want run tests in parallel  (rather than the same test in parallel), have a look at creating a testng suite xml file and stipulate numbe of threads

Comment: Yes, driver object is created at class level[static WebDriver driver;]. If I define this at method level, how other methods use the driver object? Pls tell me if I am not clear to you.

Comment: I need to run the same test class parallel so that two browsers should be launched running the test simultaneously.

Comment: Ahh, it is static. Does it need to be static? Static objects only exist once so this is definitely your problem. Try removing 'static'

Comment: I have some static methods which is using the driver object. Hence I specified as static. In this case, what is the solution?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36617/discussion-between-srikanth-n-and-robbiewareham)

Comment: Can't chat now, free in about four hours

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand your problem enough (how are you instantiating and running the commands on both drivers)...but I believe I know what you want.

If you want to do parallel testing with TestNG with multiple drivers, then I believe that you need to use `@dataProvider`.

```
@dataProvider(parallel=true, name= "drivers")
public Object[][] getDrivers(){
    return new Object[][]{{firefoxDriver},{chromeDriver}};
}

@Test(dataProvider="drivers")
public void mainRun(WebDriver driver){
    test goes here
}
```

What this does:

Before each invocation of any `@Test` that has that dataProvider, it will run your getDrivers() function, and get the drivers.

Its a two-dimensional  array because the first dimension are the sets of data you pass in to the test, while the second dimension is that set of data you want to pass in.

If this is not what you are looking for...then please be more specific in what you want.

Comment: @dataprovider is used to provide data driven tests. You do not need it to run in parallel

Comment: Yes...but he said "multiple threads with TestNG".  That screams `@dataprovider` to me.  However, it looks like the the driver being static was his problem.

Comment: Yes but "If you want to do parallel testing with TestNG with multiple drivers, then I believe that you need to use @dataProvider." is an incorrect statement and could cause future confusion.